# C++: mark classes with non-virtual destructors `final`

Tags: c++, refactoring

Do any C++ automatic-refactoring tools exist that can mark all classes with non-virtual destructors `final`? This could prevent bad inheritance choices which would potentially lead to undefined behavior.

It seems like a fairly simple Perl script could do a decent job with this, but an even better option would be something based on Clang tools.

A Windows tool would be acceptable, even if it requires an MSVC license, but I'd prefer something that can run on Debian Linux.

Comment: What operating system does it need to run on?

Comment: @Undo Preferably Linux, though it'd be easy enough to check out source code to Windows and do the refactoring there. I think I could even obtain an MSVS 2015 license if necessary.